# This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, content-security-policy

I have a Google Spreadsheet where I have the following information on specific cells in the sheet:

- *Cell **B1***: Has the URL **`http://www.google.com.co/search?q=NASA+watching+now%3A+site%3Awww.youtube.com`**
- *Cell **B2***: has the following formula: `=IMPORTXML(B1,"//title")`

Here is the [link of the Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jRqOsOGs4NbYZN-ye9SY5cPm4_dpEvMMv1ursUIqsdU/edit?usp=sharing) - if you want to test from your side.

And here is the [Google Spreadsheet I'm working on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17boExdn1kGL1Ds8aTnB3gr-zCDAKAMqvFB3Fz4_Sq5I/edit?usp=sharing) - which, I want to get the specific data:

1. Title: Text (*in the **`h3`** HTML tag of the result item*).
2. Url: Link (*in the **`<a>`** HTML tag of the result item*)
3. Description: Text next to the thumbnail of the result item.

See screenshot with the data to get using **`IMPORTXML`**:

[image: Screenshot of result item poiting the data to get with IMPORTXML]

The previous code returns the **`title`** of the given URL - in this case, the URL stored in the ***B1*** cell.

It was working without problems (*since 12/02/2022 - dd/MM/yyyy*) until today (*13/02/2022 - dd/mm/yyyy*).

I checked the Chrome console "F12 Developer tools" and I get this error:

> This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.
>
> injectIntoContentWindow @ VM364:27

By clicking the @ VM364:27 line, the following code is shown:

```
  function injectIntoContentWindow(contentWindow)
  {
    if (contentWindow && !injectedFramesHas(contentWindow))
    {
      injectedFramesAdd(contentWindow);
      try
      {
        contentWindow[eventName] = checkRequest;
        contentWindow.eval( /* ERROR with and (X) is shown here. */
          "(" + injectedToString() + ")('" + eventName + "', true);"
        );
        delete contentWindow[eventName];
      }
      catch (e) {}
    }
  }
```

Searching on the internet, I barely could get the causes of this error:

- Google Chrome update - making security stricter.
- Chrome extensions - try to disable such extensions and try again.
- CPS (*Content-Security-Policy*) - must be honest = I don't understand this point; it's from the website to scrape the data OR from Google Sheets the CPS is the root cause?
- The *solutions* given to this problem are in Python - with the use of DOMPurify - as is [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595475/12511801), but, I don't know and neither have found any clues about this problem and its solution in Google Spreadsheets.

I've tried:

- Recover previous working Google Spreadsheet version - the result is that the formula re-evaluates and no result is returned; looking in Console, the `This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment` message shows.
- [Disable Google Chrome installed extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/108665925?hl=en&msgid=108666746) - I only have AdBlock (*this code was working without issues*), anyway, I turned off, reload the spreadsheet and the error mentioned above raises in Console.
- Using another page - I tried with Wikipedia and Wiki.fandom and it works - i.e. data is returned. Probably in this case, Google injected in their searcher an script for avoid injection? - I'm really not sure, only speculating/rambling here.

Another possible cause I consider is maybe my IP was blacklisted or blocked, but, I'm not sure.

My browser information:

- Chrome version: 98.0.4758.82 (Build oficial) (64 bits) (cohort: Stable)
- Windows 10 Version 21H2 (Build 19044.1466)

Is there any way to solve this error in Google Sheets?

PS: I'm interested in know the workaround using google sheets and/or custom scripts - via *script editor/Apps Script*. The use of `IMPORTXML` function is not mandatory - I find curious that it was working and then today, not anymore.

Comment: and you want only first title or all of  them?

Comment: @player0 the title of the page, but, the desired result at the end is: (1) get the text in the "h3" tag = those are the titles of each element in the search results. (2) get the URL in the "a" tag and (3) "optional" get the text at the side of the result item.

Comment: @player0 here is the [google sheet I've created](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17boExdn1kGL1Ds8aTnB3gr-zCDAKAMqvFB3Fz4_Sq5I/edit?usp=sharing) and it works - i.e retrieves the titles and URL of the search results. Please, let me know what you see if you open this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** `This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment` error is not the root cause of the delay of the `IMPORTXML` function - probably there is other cause(s) (*outside of the developer's handling*), but, after all, the code works - [see working google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jycW08j3HdwU38jl7jK1Jz0njSzPQPw-tIPx2kRjby0/edit?usp=sharing) - just, wait until the results are shown or use another way to web-scrapping the desired data.

---

Since the `This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment` message stays appearing in the Console of the browser, but, the code I posted on my question (*and the code posted by [SO user player0 in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71106445/12511801)*) works, it seems to me that the delay of the response using `IMPORTXML` *might* be due its buggy functionality and/or some restriction Google detected by doing multiple requests.

So, here are my tips about this:

- Check very closely how the page where the data will be extracted from and its structured ***before*** doing excessive requests - or you might face a significant delay in the response of the `IMPORTXML` function - as I experienced it.
- Get more familiar with XPath and check if the data is dynamically generated in the page - this makes even harder to get the desired data using this way of scrapping.

[This is the spreadsheet with the desired results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jycW08j3HdwU38jl7jK1Jz0njSzPQPw-tIPx2kRjby0/edit?usp=sharing) - if anyone is interesed<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Check the "Results-mix" sheet (*which contains both the code I manage to create and the code provided by player0 in their answer*).

If you really want to get similar results in a less convoluted way, consider use another strategy for web-scrapping or use official APIs - when available.

Answer (score 1):

I will just leave this here:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//a/@href"), 
 "where Col1 contains 'youtube.com/'"), "\/url\?q=|&sa=.*", )))
```

[image]

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//title")
```

[image]

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//h3")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get the result immediately or did you have to wait until the results were shown in the sheet? - I'm saying this because [see image I just get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR3Qe.png) after waiting almost one hour :| - yesterday, I got the results almost instantaneously.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I got it immediately

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Maybe *could* be about my IP - could be restricted to not get the results immediately? - this is strange in my case, though. The `INDEX(UNIQUE(REGEXREPLACE([...]` you posted looks very good - I will check it closely for get the description of the results. I appreciate your help with this issue and (*if you don't mind*), I would appreciate your efforts to get the description - once I could get the URL - as I shown in my screenshot, I haven't been able to get this last data.